# Lua Roblox Scripting collector

Tags: lua, roblox

im trying to make a collector for a roblox tycoon but when i try to run the game i get this error message

> Collider is not a valid member of Part "Workspace.Template.Collector.Collider"

CODE:

```
local Collector = {}
Collector.__index = Collector

function Collector.new(tycoon, instance)
    local self = setmetatable({}, Collector)
    self.Tycoon = tycoon
    self.Instance = instance

    return self
end

function Collector:Init()
    self.Instance.Collider.Touched:Connect(function(...)
        self:OnTouched(...) 
    end)
end

function Collector:OnTouched(hitPart)
    local worth = hitPart:GetAttribute("Worth")
    if worth then
        self.Tycoon:PublishTopic("WorthChange", worth)
        hitPart:Destroy()
    end
end

return Collector
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is irrelevant as the error is saying that the part named "Collider" doesnt exist inside Workspace.Template.Collector.Collider. A solution is by creating a part and placing it inside Workspace.Template.Collector.Collider

Answer (score 0):

Well it's just saying the collider isn't a child of that part which is Collector. Check if it is inside Collector. If it is but you're still having that error, check if the name is spelled correctly. Roblox is very sensitive to capitalization.